# Mathematical Integration of a function in Python

Tags: python, function, scipy

I'm trying to integrate this function:

[image]

However I'm running into an error of:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython console>", line 1, in <module>

  File "siestats.py", line 349, in NormalDistro

    P_inner = scipy.integrate(NDfx,-dev,dev)

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

My code runs this:

```
# Definition of the mathematical function:
def NDfx(x):

    return((1/math.sqrt((2*math.pi)))*(math.e**((-.5)*(x**2))))

# This Function normailizes x, u, and o2 (position of interest, mean and st dev) 
# and then calculates the probability up to position 'x'

def NormalDistro(u,o2,x):


    dev = abs((x-u)/o2)


    P_inner = scipy.integrate(NDfx,-dev,dev)

    P_outer = 1 - P_inner

    P = P_inner + P_outer/2

    return(P)
```

Function NormalDistro is mean for import and used like this:

```
foo.NormalDistro(30,2.5,1.25)
```

As an example.

Comment: Can you tell us _which_ module object it is trying to call? Should be in the error message. Usually happens when you do "import foo" followed by "foo()" instead of "foo.bar()".

Comment: Post the entire traceback.  Just knowing what the error is without knowing what caused it doesn't help.

Comment: Since you are using `scipy`, what is your rationale to use `python` `math` functions, in your `NDfx`?

Comment: @eat what do you mean?  I don't follow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The module you are attempting to call is `scipy.integrate`, you need to call one of the functions within the module. Based on previous comments on [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/533455#533455) you are probably wanting to use  `scipy.integrate.quad()`.

Also, it returns a tuple of `(Result,MaximumError)`, so you shouldn't use `P_inner` directly in the sum for `P`, you want `P = P_inner[0] + P_outer/2`

Answer (score 2):

`return` doesn't require `()`, simply `return P` works just fine

Though this actually wouldn't fix the issue you're seeing, as `return(foo)` should also work.

More information on the error would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The integral of a gaussian is defined as the [errorfunction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function). It is available from pythons math libaray or scipy.special (if you need a vectorized function). Its called erf. Also available is erfc, the complementary  error function.